# wordpress loop inside foreach statment

Tags: php, foreach, wordpress

Im trying to make a program for a radio show website.
I have a custom field with all the days of week and I just wanna put each post in list of its corresponding day.

So far Iv got the code below and I make 7 lists for all the days but each list has all the same posts. Anyone know how to make this work? Or something else would be better?

```
<?php
$days = array(
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday',
);

$guide = array(
    'post_type' => 'shows',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'show_day',
            'value' => $dayg,
            'compare' => 'like'
            )
        )
    );
?>

<h3 class="guide">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h3>
<?php foreach($days as $dayg) { ?>

    <ul class="day">
        <h3>
            <?php echo $dayg; ?>
        </h3>

        <?php query_posts($guide); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php the_title(); echo ' | ' , the_field('show_day'); ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Anyone know

Comment: Do you want separate lists for days ???

Comment: Yes, a seperate list for each day

Comment: Than you need to add different query & loop for each days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:--

```
<?php
$days = array(
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday',
);
?>

<h3 class="guide">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h3>
<?php foreach($days as $dayg) { ?>

<?php 
$guide = array(
        'post_type' => 'shows',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                        'key' => 'show_day',
                        'value' => $dayg,
                        'compare' => 'like'
                )
        )
);
?>
    <ul class="day">
        <h3>
            <?php echo $dayg; ?>
        </h3>
        <?php query_posts($guide); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php the_title(); echo ' | ' , the_field('show_day'); ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This will work, because you are adding `$guide` variable outside the loop thats why `$dayg` is not set...